# css adding two line character for a json data

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs, json

I have a **json data** that has line characters that are present, but when I render that on html, it does add **new line character** with`style="white-space: pre-line"` property, instead I wanted to add **2 new line characters**

My json data

```
[{"id":1,"title":"Israel’s desert city of Beersheba is turning into a cybertech oasis","description":"morphing into a tech oasis.\r\nThe military’s massive relocation of its prestigious technology units.\r\nBeersheba has all of the ingredients of a vibrant security technology ecosystem, \r\n“All in all, projections are that 20,000-30,000 \r\nThe commercial sector has teamed up  cyber attacks.","pub_date":"2016-03-20T10:48:19.394643Z"},{"id":2,"title":"These are testing times: mavericks vs. ice people","description":"One of my earliest engineering jobs, before I fled hardware in favor of the (relative). \r\nThe practice of engineering soon teaches one that, .\r\nSo what do we do? We practice defense in depth. We follow the robustness principle. We “always code as \r\n…Yeah, well, that’s the idea. For my day job at HappyFunCorp I do a lot of interviews, and almost every junior develope.\r\nI don’t necessarily blame them. You can make  go.","pub_date":"2016-03-20T10:50:07.965930Z"}]
```

To be much clearer, description in json is like this

```
morphing into a tech oasis.\r\nThe military’s massive relocation of its prestigious technology units.\r\nBeersheba has all of the ingredients of a vibrant security technology ecosystem, \r\n“All in all, projections are that 20,000-30,000 \r\nThe commercial sector has teamed up  cyber attacks.
```

As we can see there are \r\n present, so here I wanted to insert **new line again** to render **2 new line charaters**

My controller

```
<div class="blog-post">
 <p class="blog-post-title">{{ post.title }}</p>
 <p class="blog-post-meta"><i class="fa fa-clock-o">&nbsp {{ post.pub_date|date  }}</i> </p>
 <span style="white-space: pre-line">{{ post.description }}</span>
```

---

what should be done to render the output with 2 new line charaters for `{{ post.description }}`?

My expecting output to be like this

```
morphing into a tech oasis.

The military’s massive relocation of its prestigious technology units.

Beersheba has all of the ingredients of a vibrant security technology ecosystem, 

“All in all, projections are that 20,000-30,000 

The commercial sector has teamed up  cyber attacks.
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: `post.description.replace(/\n/g, '\n\n')`

Comment: @azium..where should I add it?

Comment: Either make a filter and pipe it in your view `{{ post.description | extraNewLine }}`, or in your controller.

Answer (score 0):

Remove all /r /n in JSON from Controller by regex::

```
 post.description.replace(/(?:\\[rn]|[\r\n]+)+/g, "")
```